# ArcMap: extracting overlapped buffers

Tags: arcmap, buffer, intersection

I have a set of points in ArcMap which I create a buffer for each point. Then I use intersect to extract the overlapping buffers. The result is something like this:
[image]

The lighter color are the overlapped layer. Weird thing is that on the left, the overlapped buffer is rather incorrect, is it? Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are there two (duplicate) points directly on top of one another in the center of the completely filled circle?

Comment: @dmahr, I think you just pointed something I stupidly overlooked. Indeed the "weird" looking overlapped buffers are actually 6 points (6 buffers) whereas the right one are just perfectly 2 overlapped buffers. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @dmahr  could you add this as an answer please; all good work deserves a turn!  Thanks Matt

Comment: @Hairy Done! I'll do this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

(Added this as an answer, as requested)

You may have multiple, duplicate points overlying one another in the "incorrectly" filled circle.  I would use the Identify tool and draw a marquee around the center of the "incorrectly" filled circle and see if there are multiple point features in the Identify pane.

Comment: cheers fir that